# How to configure multiple query's and query specific topic in kafka source connector properties?

Tags: sql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to get data from SQL into kafka topics using Source Connector, so for that i configured source properties file, i am getting whole data from the SQL table into Kafka topic, but i don't want whole data from the SQL table, I want specific column from the table,table could be a multiple, Main point is i dont no how to configure multiple topics per query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the jdbc source connector

> I want specific column from the table,

Then add the `query` property to select individual columns.

> configure multiple topics per query.

Source connectors generally only output to one topic. You can run multiple connectors with different queries and output topics